# Can't get a responce in retrofit Android Studio

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

I am using ngrok to put my local php project into the web. I need to get an id of a user in a login action. My Android gives me

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found, url=http://ab873755.ngrok.io/site/login?login=123&pass=123456}

Can't get a responce in retrofit Android Studio. Url is correct. Checked it in Postman

When I put this url into Postman it's all fine and gives the right response. 
This page returns

> {"user_id":1}

```
package com.example.backgroundservice.ui.login;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class WResponce {
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private String user_id;

    public String getUserId() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUserId(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.backgroundservice.ui.login;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface JSONPlaceHolderApi {
    @GET("site/login")
    public Call<WResponce> getResponce(
            @Query("login") String login,
            @Query("pass") String password
    );
}
```

```
package com.example.backgroundservice.ui.login;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class NetworkClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://ab873755.ngrok.io/";
    public static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient(){
        if (retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.backgroundservice.ui.login;

import android.net.http.HttpResponseCache;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.backgroundservice.R;
import com.example.backgroundservice.ReceiveData;

import java.io.IOException;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Thread mUiThread;
    private JSONPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }

    public void login(View view) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        final EditText username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText password = findViewById(R.id.password);

        Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient();
        jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JSONPlaceHolderApi.class);
        Call call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getResponce(username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());

        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    WResponce res = (WResponce) response.body();
                    String a = ((WResponce) response.body()).getUserId();
                    Log.d("myres",a);
                    Log.d("myres",response.body().toString());
                }
                Log.d("mymsg",response.message());
                Log.d("mymsg",response.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Is api url real? If so then it's not working. To check try from different devices.

Comment: Restart your ngrok tunnel and get a new URL. ngrok tunnel free version expires very soon.

Comment: I can't be connected to wi-fi all the time. So I am restarting ngrok very often and getting new urls. So you will not be able to check my api. I just hoped someone could see some mistake in my code or maybe faced the same issue. I've been thinking if the problem is in my backend. Like if I am returning just string like $str="user_id:".$model->id; ($model->id is an id from my database. I am using Yii2 framework) and my program is expecting some type of json object and finds only text/html. Also tried to return json_encode(array("user_id"=>$model->id)); Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Put base `url = http://ab873755.ngrok.io`. You are not supposed to put the path in base url. Put the path in `@GET("sites/login").`

Make sure your ngrok url is active one. Seems like it was expired

Comment: I just forgot to remove this line. It does not do anything. I never use it

Comment: public static final String BASE_URL = "http://ab873755.ngrok.io/site/"; This is what I am using. But at first it was like public static final String BASE_URL = "http://ab873755.ngrok.io/"; and  @Get("site/login"). Doesn't work anyway

Comment: Check with the configuration I specified and get error log inside OnFailure.

Answer (score 0):

The `URL` you are using is not working in `POSTMAN`.

**Things to Note**

> 1) Whether you are passing anything in Authorization or not.
>   2)
>   Whether you are sending anything in Headers

Incorrect Response in Postman (Screenshot)
[image]

Comment: If there was authorization error then you could get 401 error.

Comment: @Bek maybe issue with headers

Comment: I suspect ngrok tunnel expired. As you see, Tunnel ab873755.ngrok.io not found

Comment: This should be because my PC was off. Ngrok is on while my PC is on.